# How insert a grant_type in a HttpURLConnection post method in Android?

Tags: android

Here are one example of a "normal" post method that works for me:

```
private Reader testPostAuth() throws IOException {
        Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        params.put("city_id", "1");
        params.put("status", "2");

        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
            if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            postData.append('=');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
        }
        byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) Connection.TEST_ALISSON.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
        //conn.setRequestProperty("","");

        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

        Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        return in;
    }
```

Now I need get authorization token. How can I make this (down) request with same method post?

```
curl -X POST -d grant_type=password&username=admin&password=dm123456" -u"LrNjB6YMh24qvcosr5ie0l5ioGB7WbSVkMkXR9dg:hw7SxDggT0OzaxVOwpn4q02lsHZfxWF6pIqCAVmzDWgiIxVrac6os1KDNGdgq0GPg4m3u6hXU25NZS9UiF3VOH4NSHiHhLIRF45lo8ZkrsODGtetE3slWWYjCYas8XrT" http://localhost:8000/o/token/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private Reader testPostAuth() throws IOException {
    Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    params.put("grant_type", "password");
    params.put("username", "admin");
    params.put("password", "dm123456");

    StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
        if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        postData.append('=');
        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
    }
    byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) Connection.TEST_ALISSON.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));

    /* BASIC AUTH START */
    String username = "LrNjB6YMh24qvcosr5ie0l5ioGB7WbSVkMkXR9dg";
    String password = "hw7SxDggT0OzaxVOwpn4q02lsHZfxWF6pIqCAVmzDWgiIxVrac6os1KDNGdgq0GPg4m3u6hXU25NZS9UiF3VOH4NSHiHhLIRF45lo8ZkrsODGtetE3slWWYjCYas8XrT";
    String userpass = username + ":" + password;
    String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userpass.getBytes()));
    conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
    /* BASIC AUTH END */

    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

    Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    return in;
}
```

It's work for me ;D